# Ошибка "Stack overflow" - что это и как ее избежать?

Tags: c++, overflow

Можете объяснить, когда возникает эта ошибка и как от нее избавиться?

Comment: обычно это значит что есть проблемы с рекурсией, в большинстве случаев когда задаётся этот вопрос - нету условия выхода из рекурсии.

Comment: Еще появляется, когда вы объявляете слишком большой локальный массив (внутри функции). Обычно размер стека ограничен несколькими мегабайтами.

Comment: Обычно эта ошибка бывает из-за @PashaPash.

Comment: @Other, почему?

Comment: @maestro, этот пользователь умудрился сломать `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/`, ирония :)

Comment: @Other, что он такое натворил?

Answer (score 12):

Это означает, что в стеке недостаточно места.

Причины - например, слишком глубокая рекурсия (редко), или слишком большие локальные переменные (куда чаще), или и то и другое сразу :)

Как избавиться? Опять же, можно просто в настройках компилятора поднять размер стека.

Но надежнее и лучше - посмотреть, нет ли слишком глубокой (вплоть до бесконечности) рекурсии, заменить локальные массивы на выделяемые динамически.

```
int f()
{
    int a[1000000];
```

практически гарантированно даст переполнение стека. В отличие от

```
int f()
{ 
    int * a = new int[1000000];  // Только не забудьте потом удалить...
```

или

```
    vector<int> a(1000000);
```

Словом, смотрите, кто съедает много стековой памяти, и избавляйтесь от него...

Answer (score 1):

Про стек и другие типы данных:

- Стековые данные. На них память выделяется при заходе в процедуру и освобождается при её завершении. Максимальный размер стека программы составляет 1 GB и для 32-битных, и для 64-битных приложений. (Размерстека задаётся линковщиком и по умолчанию составляет 1 MB)
- Статические данные. Ограничение накладывается на размер самого исходного кода программы и размер статически выделяемой памяти. В языке C++ такие данные обычно представлены переменными, объявленными на глобальном уровне вне процедур. Как для 32-битных, так и для 64-битных программ, ограничение на размер статически выделяемой    памяти равно 2 GB.
- Динамические данные. Это данные, память на которые динамически выделяется во время исполнения программы. В C++ такое выделение обычно осуществляется функцией malloc или оператором new. В 32-битных программах размер динамически выделяемой памяти ограничен 2 GB, в 64-битных — 8 TB.

У 32-битного приложения запущенного в 32-битной Windows суммарный размер всех перечисленных типов данных не должен превышать 2 GB. (Практически ограничение равно 1.75GB из-за требований к памяти самой операционной системы) 32-битная программа, собранная с ключом /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:YES может выделять до 3-х гигабайт памяти, если 32-битная операционная система Windows запущена с ключом /3gb. Эта же 32-битная программа, запущенная на 64-битной системе, может выделить почти 4 GB памяти (на практике около 3.5 GB).

Ограничения на максимальный размер статически-выделяемой и стековой памяти одинаковы для 32-х и 64-х битных Windows приложений. Это связано с форматом типа файлов Portable Executable (PE), который используется в Windows для описания exe и dll файлов. Статические и стековые данные располагаются в первых 2-х GB адресного пространства приложения. **Стоит помнить, что данные ограничения накладываются самой операционной системой и не зависят от используемого компилятора.**

Данная информация взята от сюда: https://www.viva64.com/ru/k/0036/

Вывод, следующий:

1. Как написал коллега [**Harry**] в ответе...

> Это означает, что в стеке недостаточно места.

2. Зная выше описанные ограничения и возможные причины появления данной ошибки, Вы всегда можете проектировать Ваши решения, что бы  избегать подобных проблем.