# stack overflow в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++

Почему так?

```
bool arr[256][4096];
arr[20][100] = true;
cout << arr[20][101]; // Stack overflow
```

VS2015, тест на онлайн компиляторах ошибку не выявляет :(

Comment: Не обьявляйте стековые переменные бооольших размеров. У вас переменная в функции, функция в рекурсию точно не входит? Ну допустим не входит. Но что б понять сколько сьели стека... можно посмотреть либо разницу esp либо проссумировать все локальные переменные в стековых окнах.

Comment: @nick_n_a а как узнать, какой размер большой, а какой нет. Где посмотреть, с чем сравнить?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос. это указывается в параметрах линкера. У вас студия - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8cxs58a6.aspx в опциях сборки указывается размер стека. этот размер увеличить можно... но я советую всётаки большие размеры или обьявлять статикой, или делать malloc/new.

Comment: У студии размер стека по умолчанию (для 32бит) — 1 МБ. А вы как раз 1Мб и забираете, а там ещё 20-50 стековых окон на которые 1-2 кб стека тоже понадобится.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да уж, тяжко мне будет с вашим C++
в дельфийском мире таких граблей на ровном месте нету

Comment: @Robert если Вы с ними не сталкивались - не значит что их там нет. Просто по дефолту размер стэка там побольше. Насколько я помню

Comment: Какая у вас вообще цель? Допишите слово `static bool arr[256][4096]` и не мучайте стек. (только тогда ф-цию нельзя вызывать рекурсивно или паралельно с другого потока). Создайте arr динамическую. Пишите на c# там будет arr всегда динамическая.

Comment: @vegorov, размер стека там 1 мегабайт. Но почему-то при объявлении там двумерного массива как типа и занимающего 16 мегабайт, с ним прекрасно работается и стек не переполняется(

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну вы в принципе мне на вопрос о причинах ответили, большое вам спасибо :)

Comment: @Robert вам не кажется странным возможность в 1мб запихнуть 16? Может этот массив все-таки не в стеке храниться?

Comment: Возможно делфи делает её динамической, потому что при стеке 1Мб не может присутствовать переменная на 16Мб - это противоречит всякой логике. В с++ есть возможность обьявить динамической, а делфи вас просто не спрашивает. Но благодаря тому что локальную переменную можно сделать как статической, как стековой так и динамической - у с++ больше гибкости чем у делфи.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, кажется, я тоже сразу подумал, что там как-то иначе это внутри реализовано

Comment: @nick_n_a, похоже, что так оно и есть. Только что объявил огромный двумерный массив в делфи и никакого оверфлоу =)

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, пожалуйста, подскажите, как динамически создать такой тип:

typedef bool flags[256][65536];

все мои мучения с new тщетны(

Comment: Вы обязательно хотите такую форму двумерного массива? Вообще, стандартная библиотека содержит специализацию std::vector для типа bool, эффективно использующую память. И работать с ним будет не намного сложнее: flags[65536 * y + x]

Comment: @mrNAE, да мне этот массив хранить в двоичном файле. Каждый булев флаг - это настройка
256 групп и в каждой 65536 настроек

Comment: @Robert, смотрите какая штука, если массив флагов вещь критичная по памяти, то имеет смысл хранить каждый флаг в бите: 256*65536/8=2МБ этим занимается `std::vector<bool>`. Массив как у вас займёт 16МБ так как bool в данном случае занимает 1 байт. Делать вектор векторов - лишняя трата памяти на указатели, да и скинуть в файл проблема. Хотите упростить использование - сделайте отображение двумерного массива в одномерный: std::vector<unsigned char>flags(256*65536)... bool flag(int setting, int group){return  flags[65536 * group + setting];}

Comment: @mrNAE, большое спасибо за совет :) я тоже думал об использовании битовых флагов. Тем не менее, C++ решил временно отложить, слишком плохо знаю этот язык, несмотря на когда-то давно прочитанные умные книжки. На делфи я пишу разные сложные штуки, а здесь спотыкаюсь на мелочах.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочешь именно матрицу bool-ов фиксированных размеров:

```
#include <memory>
...

typedef bool t_arr[256][4096];
std::unique_ptr<t_arr> p_arr(new t_arr);
(*p_arr)[20][100] = true;
t_arr& arr=*p_arr; // эту ссылку используем, если лениво каждый раз разыменовывать указатель.
arr[20][100] = true;
cout << arr[20][101];
```

для современных компиляторов можно лаконичнее:

```
auto p_arr=std::make_unique< bool[256][4096] >();
auto& arr=*p_arr;
arr[20][100] = true;
cout << arr[20][101];
```

Другой путь ("Более С++-й"), стандартные контейнеры:

```
#include <vector>
...

std::vector< std::vector< bool > > arr( 256, std::vector< bool >( 4096 ) );
arr[20][100] = true;
cout << arr[20][101];
```

Недостаток второго подхода - нет сплошного поля памяти (будет сделано несколько 257 аллокаций, вместо одной, и код получится менее дружественный к кешу процессора). Достоинство: будет использовано меньше памяти (за счет специализированного std::vector< bool >, как массива битовых флагов, а не bool-ов).

Comment: Контейнер unique_ptr освободит память при выходе из ф-ции?

Comment: Да. Только это "умный указатель", а не контейнер. Он вызовет delete в своем деструкторе,

Comment: Все варианты довольно с++. Здесь вполне можно без std::unique_ptr: `t_arr *p_arr = new t_arr` и где-нибудь delete p_arr; Но это не ответ на исходный вопрос, а вот ответ: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623160/Ошибка-stack-overflow-как-избежать-и-что-это?rq=1